# Как изменить курс валют в виджете?

Tags: php, javascript, парсер, iframe, виджет

Есть сервис, который предоставляет код виджета валют https://ru.tradingview.com/
Мой код для курса:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://ru.tradingview.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">MERCURIUS PAYMENTS</span></a> от TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-overview.js" async>
  {
  "showChart": true,
  "locale": "ru",
  "largeChartUrl": "",
  "width": "400",
  "height": "600",
  "plotLineColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 1)",
  "plotLineColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 1)",
  "gridLineColor": "rgba(233, 233, 234, 1)",
  "scaleFontColor": "rgba(214, 216, 224, 1)",
  "belowLineFillColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 0.05)",
  "belowLineFillColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 0.05)",
  "symbolActiveColor": "rgba(242, 250, 254, 1)",
  "tabs": [
    {
      "title": "MERCURIUS PAYMENTS",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "FX:EURUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:GBPUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDJPY"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDCHF"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:AUDUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDCAD"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Forex",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "FX:EURUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:GBPUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDJPY"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDCHF"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:AUDUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDCAD"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Forex"
    }
  ]
}
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Код на фронтенде:

```
<div class="tradingview-widget-container" style="width: 400px; height: 600px;">
  <iframe scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" src="https://s.tradingview.com/marketoverviewwidgetembed/?locale=ru#%7B%22showChart%22%3Atrue%2C%22largeChartUrl%22%3A%22%22%2C%22width%22%3A%22400%22%2C%22height%22%3A%22600%22%2C%22plotLineColorGrowing%22%3A%22rgba(60%2C%20188%2C%20152%2C%201)%22%2C%22plotLineColorFalling%22%3A%22rgba(255%2C%2074%2C%20104%2C%201)%22%2C%22gridLineColor%22%3A%22rgba(233%2C%20233%2C%20234%2C%201)%22%2C%22scaleFontColor%22%3A%22rgba(214%2C%20216%2C%20224%2C%201)%22%2C%22belowLineFillColorGrowing%22%3A%22rgba(60%2C%20188%2C%20152%2C%200.05)%22%2C%22belowLineFillColorFalling%22%3A%22rgba(255%2C%2074%2C%20104%2C%200.05)%22%2C%22symbolActiveColor%22%3A%22rgba(242%2C%20250%2C%20254%2C%201)%22%2C%22tabs%22%3A%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%22MERCURIUS%20PAYMENTS%22%2C%22symbols%22%3A%5B%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AEURUSD%22%7D%2C%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AGBPUSD%22%7D%2C%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AUSDJPY%22%7D%2C%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AUSDCHF%22%7D%2C%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AAUDUSD%22%7D%2C%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AUSDCAD%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22title%22%3A%22Forex%22%2C%22symbols%22%3A%5B%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AEURUSD%22%7D%2C%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AGBPUSD%22%7D%2C%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AUSDJPY%22%7D%2C%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AUSDCHF%22%7D%2C%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AAUDUSD%22%7D%2C%7B%22s%22%3A%22FX%3AUSDCAD%22%7D%5D%2C%22originalTitle%22%3A%22Forex%22%7D%5D%2C%22utm_source%22%3A%22www.arefeva.com.ua%22%2C%22utm_medium%22%3A%22widget_new%22%2C%22utm_campaign%22%3A%22market_overview%22%7D" style="box-sizing: border-box; height: calc(568px); width: 400px;"></iframe>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://ru.tradingview.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">MERCURIUS PAYMENTS</span></a> от TradingView</div>

<style>
  .tradingview-widget-copyright {
    font-size: 13px !important;
    line-height: 32px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    color: #9db2bd !important;
  }

  .tradingview-widget-copyright .blue-text {
    color: #3bb3e4 !important;
  }

  .tradingview-widget-copyright a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #9db2bd !important;
  }

  .tradingview-widget-copyright a:visited {
    color: #9db2bd !important;
  }

  .tradingview-widget-copyright a:hover .blue-text {
    color: #38acdb !important;
  }

  .tradingview-widget-copyright a:active .blue-text {
    color: #299dcd !important;
  }

  .tradingview-widget-copyright a:visited .blue-text {
    color: #3bb3e4 !important;
  }
  </style></div>
```

Нужно каким-то способом изменить котировки в первой вкладке [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сайт для примера работы кода - http://www.arefeva.com.ua/test/

Написал свой скрипт на JS, но он не работает почему-то:

```
jQuery('.js-symbol-last').ready(function($) {
  jQuery('.js-symbol-last').html(function(index, oldhtml) {
    var newhtml = (oldhtml*1.003).toFixed(5) ;
    return newhtml;
  });
});
```

Заметил, что сработает только если в консоле разработчика сменить контекст Js:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не работает, потому что widget находится в отдельном фрейме

Comment: Спарсить данные через Php возможно?